Acrobat JS list/print all PDF form field names "in order" - and direct to csv delmited or excel?
The code below lists all the field names in a PDF.  However, it does so in alphabetical order.  I would like to be able to get these into Excel, but in the order they appear through the PDF form itself.
Side question, whats the save as file option here - excel or csv?
Thanks all.
console.show();
console.clear();
console.println("Number of fields: " + this.numFields);
for(var i = 0; i < this.numFields; i++)
{
    console.println(this.getNthFieldName(i));
}


Try to see if the answers from this post are helpful.

Ever get a solution for this?
